# HTML: formatting instead of WYSIWYG

Tags: wysiwyg

I personally tend to hate WYSIWYG editors. They take time to load and just love plain old HTML, so I just disable the editor entirely. However, I would like to have HTML from the database to be prettyfied or beautified or ... well, loooking sexy for the time of editing with indents, newlines, etc. Any module out there that does that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a patch [here](https://drupal.org/node/1377948) to provide support for [Ace](http://ace.c9.io/) code editor in wysiwyg module.

From Ace's website:

> Ace is an embeddable code editor written in JavaScript. It matches the
>   features and performance of native editors such as Sublime, Vim and
>   TextMate. It can be easily embedded in any web page and JavaScript
>   application. Ace is maintained as the primary editor for Cloud9 IDE
>   and is the successor of the Mozilla Skywriter (Bespin) project.

I'm not aware of any other source code wysiwyg editor supported by wysiwyg.module.

Answer (score 2):

You're looking for [HTML Tidy module](https://drupal.org/project/htmltidy).

> This module tidies Drupal's HTML output with HTML Tidy by optionally
>   sanitizing it when it is saved or when it is displayed, like a
>   traditional input formatter. Missing and mis-ordered tag components
>   are replaced and reordered automatically so that user input doesn't
>   break site structure with open tags and the like.
>
> User interface configuration supports:
>
> Code indenting: Automatically format HTML for easier reading, or strip
>   indenting for proper parsing and display in the less compliant
>   browsers. Word wrapping: Automatically wrap lines in an intelligent
>   fashion once they get to a specified length Info/Warning/Error
>   information: Optionally appended to pages and includes details about
>   the wrong HTML attributes and W3C validation info.

Comment: Correct me if I got it wrong. HTML Tidy tidies up the Drupal's output and the edited HTML chunk for a particular node is not "output" and is therefore not formatter/indented. I am looking more into something similar to markitup - a tool for the HTML editing.

Comment: You need to create a text format and then you can use it on fields

Comment: Somehow this does not work. https://www.dropbox.com/s/uezp2j87t1asfhd/Screen%20Shot%202013-09-14%20at%2010.03.37%20AM.png

Comment: Your text format is showing Full HTML in your screenshot. You need to create an HTML Tidy text format and use that.

Comment: It works now and I played the settings for some time, however, the indenting and word wrapping is not as I expected, it simply wraps at a certain position. I expected unnecessary spaces to be stripped and the HTML code reformatted with nested tags taken into account, etc.

Comment: I believe a similar question was raised here https://drupal.org/node/860554, but not closed without any real answer.